# Create folder on desktop in Igor

Tags: igor

I'm wondering if anybody knows how to create a folder on the desktop of your computer using code in Igor.

I know how to delete a folder on my physical computer

```
NewPath MyFolder "C:Users:MyNameUser:Desktop:MyFolder:"
DeleteFolder/P=MyFolder
```

But I don't see anything similar to this for creating a folder. I know how to create a data folder within Igor

```
NewDataFolder root:MyFolder
```

But can't figure out how to create a new folder on my desktop or something. Anybody have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer

All you need to do is say

```
NewPath/C MyFolder "C:User:MyNameUser:Desktop:MyFolder"
```

The /C flag creates a folder rather than just a reference path